# Extending LINQ-based Specification Pattern to implement subsumption

Tags: linq, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, linq-expressions, specification-pattern

There are a lot of LINQ-based implementations of the Composite Specification Pattern.  I have not seen one that used Subsumption.

Are there any such examples that have been documented (blogs, etc.) or published as open source?  I have an idea and proof of concept for how this could work by having an ExpressionVisitor translate every specification into a canonical logical form (CNF/DNF), but I am concerned that this is overly complicated.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you mean conditional where clause in Linq ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am concerned that this is overly complicated. Is there a better way?

The short answer is "No, there isn't" <sup>1</sup>

The long answer: The "overly complicated" captures the essence of the problem: it is NP-hard. Here is a short informal proof relying upon the fact that the [*satisfiability problem* is NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem):

- Suppose that you have two Boolean formulas, `A` and `B`
- You need to test if `A` implies `B`, or equivalently `¬A | B` for all assignments of variables upon which `A` and `B` depend. In other words, you need a proof that `F = ¬A | B` is a *tautology*.
- Suppose that the tautology test can be performed in polynomial time
- Consider `¬F`, the inverse of `F`. `F` is *satisfiable* if and only if `¬F` is not a *tautology*
- Use the hypothetical polynomial algorithm to test `¬F` for being a tautology
- The answer to "is `F` satisfiable" is the inverse of the answer to "is `¬F` a tautology"
- Therefore, an existence of a polynomial tautology checker would imply that the satisfiability problem is in `P`, and that `P=NP`.

Of course the fact that the problem is NP-hard does not mean that there would be no solutions for practical cases: in fact, your approach with the conversion to a canonical form may produce OK results in many real-world situations. However, an absence of a known "good" algorithm often discourages active development of practical solutions<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> With the obligatory "unless `P=NP`" disclaimer.

<sup>2</sup> Unless a "reasonably good" solution would do, which may very well be the case for your problem, if you allow for "false negatives".

Comment: +1, Question: are you using tautology in the formal logic sense of the word or is there a similar but differently qualified definition in CS?  Its my understanding that a proposition is tautologous iff it can be derived from the empty set of SC sentences.  This would not adequately describe what I am trying to prove, because I have an extensive knowledge-base/database to derive from as well.  On another note, the problem is difficult, but has been solved efficiently before..   Right now, I'm looking into Prolog, Euler and Microsoft Solver Foundation.

Comment: @smartcaveman I am using tautology in the formal logic sense of the word: to prove that expression `A` subsumes `B`, you need to show that `A => B` is always true, i.e. can be derived from the empty set of premises. The only reason I mentioned it was to get to the satisfiability problem, which is known to be NP-complete. Note that only `A => B` must be a tautology; the individual expressions `A` and `B` can be, and in all non-trivial cases, will be, based on non-empty sets of premises. The bigger that set is, the harder is to prove the subsumption of `B` by `A`.

Comment: so I had another idea as to how to address this more practically - still working it out.  Instead of a pure rewriting, I could create a square-of-opposition model for each predicate and require that all my predicates are in syllogistic form.  This seems like it might mitigate the complexity, b/c the content would be normalized rather than the formal representation - since my domain is a business application, I think it could be expressive enough. Any thoughts?

Comment: @smartcaveman Changing the representation would not change the fundamental hardness of the problem. Even if you normalize everything to 3-CNF, you're still in the NP space. Essentially, you are building a first-order theorem prover - it's not easy, unless you significantly restrict your predicates. Allowing false negatives in a few corner cases could be another tradeoff, if your application can tolerate it.

Comment: can you elaborate more about what you had in mind re: allowing false negatives for corner cases, or link me to somewhere that discusses this variation?

Comment: @smartcaveman I meant trying a symbolic approach, where two expression trees are checked for [subgraph isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem). Since trees are *planar graphs*, you can adopt a [linear-time algorithm](http://jgaa.info/accepted/99/Eppstein99.3.3.pdf) to find a match. Unfortunately, finding such matches would place undue restrictions on the representation of your expressions. As the result, it will be possible to construct a pair of expressions that contain a match, but the symbolic algorithm would not find it.

Comment: @smartcaveman For example, a simplistic symbolic approach would not find a match between `¬B & ¬C` and `A | ¬(B | C)`, because it does not know about DeMorgan's laws. You can certainly make lots of improvements to eliminate simple cases like this, but you wouldn't be able to cover them all.

Comment: thank you for clearing that up - I see what you mean now about the false negatives.  I don't think I'm okay with making that compromise, however.  I wouldn't consider DeMorgan's laws to be a "corner case"...  am I mistaken in thinking that a lexical comparison of alphabetically sorted expression symbols in CNF would catch all cases?

Comment: @smartcaveman If both expressions are CNFs, you no longer need DeMorgan's laws. You don't even need to sort, just run a subgraph isomorphism algorithm on the two expression trees. It's getting to CNF that's going to be tricky if you take this approach.